# Как исключить паттерн из совпадений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь выбрать слова, больше 1 символа, и так же исключить из этих слов числа. Сделал пример https://regex101.com/r/5QVvXp/1/. Почему ".0" (и другие числа после точки) входят в совпадения?

Само выражение `(?!-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\S{2,}`

Текст        `-553.2  3442   тут.тут  там-там3  -133.0  235.5`

В результате нужны только `тут.тут` и `там-там3`

Comment: Вы сами себе противоречите: `исключить из этих слов числа` и `В результате нужны только тут.тут и там-там3`

Comment: Наверное, под числами подразумеваются «слова» исключительно из цифр, а не смешение букв и цифр.

Comment: Посмотрите на этот пример https://regex101.com/r/viQo04/1

Comment: Исключить нужно отдельные числа, то есть если слово представляет из себя число, тогда оно не нужно. Я думал, мои намерения будут и так ясны из моей попытки

Comment: @vsemozhebuty правильно меня понял.

Comment: @Эдуард я не знаю какой диапазон символов входит в \pL и какие символы могут быть в словах, поэтому иду от обратного пытаясь исключить числа, а не выбрать нужное

Comment: @Xenamel в группу \pL входят Литеральные символы, проще говоря буквы (латиница). Для кириллицы нужно добавить модификатор u.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вам подойдёт чуть более простая регулярка? Правда, она будет отсеивать формально и скопление цифр с несколькими точками, то есть строго говоря не только правильные числа. Но, возможно, это для вас несущественно. Пример на JavaScript:

```js
const string = ' -553.2  3442   тут.тут  там-там3  -133.0  235.5';

console.log(string.match(/(?!-?[\d.]+)\S{2,}/g));
```

Для страховки можно ещё добавить утверждения нулевой длины: чтобы попадали только слова, окружённые пробелами или границами строки, если ваш диалект регулярок их поддерживает. Но имейте в виду, что наличие пунктуации рядом со словами будет требовать дополнительных усилий, если не хотите, чтобы пунктуация попадала в слова (скобки, кавычки, запятые и т.д.).

```js
const string = ' -553.2  3442   тут.тут  там-там3  -133.0  235.5';

console.log(string.match(/(?<=^|\s)(?!-?[\d.]+)\S{2,}(?=\s|$)/g));
```